# Javascript function invocation without function calls in HTML body?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a small problem relating to combining HTML and Javascript. I would want
to call JS -functions with parameters without need for any button click or trigger like onchange or input (if there's one?).
Now I'm using "onclick" in my button tag.

I read the appealing Wikipedia article about [unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and
there was an example like this:

Traditional way to code:

```
<input type="text" name="date" onchange="validateDate()" />
```

But Unobtrusive way to go would be:

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
```

and in Javascript...

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('date').onchange = validateDate;
};
```

I'm looking for a solution when `onload` can be replaced some other event like input by user or when content is changed by user.

Is there a way to invoke a function without the need for an `"onclick"` attribute in the button tag?

Comment: the code you posted answers your own question ... the `window.onload` will always be required to ensure that the javascript that does the real work of attaching functions to events only does so once the DOM is loaded

Comment: Yep, you're right, there's no button -tag in the question... But it's possible to thing to replace input -tag with button tag and use onclick or whatever onchange etc in button -tag. If there was button tag, then there could be p -tag with id "date" too in my code. I'm not going to post new code example, if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for solution when onload can be replaced some other event like input by user...

All of the events are available that way, `onxyz`. So `onclick`, `onchange`, `onmouseover`, etc.

Note that using the `onxyz` properties is old-style. The new way (dating back more than 15 years) that plays nicely with others is to use `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on old IE, such as IE8 and earlier).

```
document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("change", validateDate, false);
```

The good thing about `addEventListener`/`attachEvent` is that you can have more than one handler for the same event on an element (hence "plays nicely with others").

---

Note: In your example, you're hooking up the event **very late** in the page load process. The `load` event doesn't fire until all images and other links resources have fully downloaded.

Instead, just make sure your script is at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Then you can access the elements defined above it, no need to wait for `load`:

```
<html>
<!-- ... -->
<input type="text" name="date" onchange="validateDate()" />
<!-- ... -->
<script>
(function() {
    "use strict";

    document.getElementById("date").addEventListener("change", validateDate, false);

    function validateDate() {
        // ...
    }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the use of a scoping function to avoid creating globals.